# Using continue in try-catch to prevent script termination when exception is thrown

Tags: php, try-catch, php-7

I want to convert an old code to use exception, but it shouldn't stop when exception is thrown. That's the old code:

```
function update()
{
 foreach ($this->instances as $id => $instance)
 {
  if ($instance->exists())
  {
   if (!$instance->save())
   {
        $this->setError($instance->getError());
        continue;
   }
   continue;
  }
}
```

If I want to use try catch block, do I need to use continue to avoid the script stop? That's the code with try-catch:

```
function update()
{
 foreach ($this->instances as $id => $instance)
 {
  if ($instance->exists())
  {
   try
   {
    $instance->save();
   }
   catch (exception $e)
   {
    echo $e->getMessage();
   }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add a `continue` keyword.

If an exception is thrown in the `try` block, the code in the `catch` block will be executed. After that the rest of the code will be executed normally.

Read the [section about exceptions in the language reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for details.